# MaterialViewPager library add some Text to CardViews

Tags: android

I am using this library: https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager.
I want to add some text to the CardViews. Every CardView should have its own text.

Comment: Add `TextView` in `list_item_card_small.xml' and `list_item_card_big.xml' files.

Comment: I added a textview to this but how can I add different text to the cardviews because in the adapter: textview.setText("BLA"); and then every cardview has the thext "BLA"..

Comment: Learn this: [RecyclerView Example](http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-recyclerview-tutorial/)